# it works locally on IIS but on the host it gives this error! what should I do?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Source Error:

```
public virtual ShoppingCartExample.Cart SCart {
    get {
        return ((ShoppingCartExample.Cart)(this.GetPropertyValue("SCart")));
    }
    set {
```

Source File:

> c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2faf0579\37b1b4f4\App_Code.1mhfv5r1.3.cs    Line: 21

Comment: Check your connection string.  Can the host access the Sql Server that the your connection relates to?

Comment: Your hosting provider does not have ASP.NET 4.0 installed. As its evident from the error message, they are trying to compile it using framework 2.0